# Getting Null exception , base controller throwing null exception when executing test cases Put_IsUnlockUser_ReturnsTrue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public ResponseTransferObject Put(AccountPutRequest request)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.UnlockUser))
        {
            if (!Session.RoleName.Equals("Administrator", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return object
            }
}

public void Put_IsUnlockUser_ReturnsTrue()  
{  
    AccountController accountController = new AccountController();
    ResponseTransferObject responseTransferObject = new ResponseTransferObject();
    //AccountPutRequest ar = new AccountPutRequest();   
    try
    {
        responseTransferObject = accountController.Put(new AccountPutRequest { UnlockUser = "Wind" });
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(responseTransferObject.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(false);      
    }
}

public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public SessionUser Session { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        Session = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyUser"] as SessionUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume you mean a NullReferenceException

Comment: yes.can i skip base controller  is there anyway

Comment: My application session is getting validated by the base cotroller that'swhy it is throwing exception, is there any way. can i rewrite my application code, so that the testcases issue will be resolved.